# Proper usage of 'end_with?'?

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to gather all files in my local directory with a .xlsx file format and pull them into my AWS S3 Bucket, however, my method for doing that

```
attr_reader :bucket, :object_key, :input_file_path

    def initialize(bucket:, object_key:, input_file_path:)
      @bucket = bucket
      @object_key = object_key
      @input_file_path = input_file_path
    end

    def call
      return unless input_file_path.end_with?(".xslx")
      object = s3_resource.bucket(bucket).object(object_key)
      object.upload_file(input_file_path)
    end
```

returns me

```
[5] pry(main)> Accounting::Datev::Utils::ExcelUtil.new(bucket: nil,  object_key:nil,  input_file_path: nil).call
NoMethodError: undefined method `end_with?' for nil:NilClass
```

Am I using [end_with?](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/end_with%3F) incorrectly?

Comment: What does that error tell you?  What does `undefined method X for nil:NilClass` means?

Comment: @razvans that I should create a method defining the input file path?

Comment: What do you expect `nil.end_with?` to do? Nil is not a string; it doesn't end with anything...

Comment: You might want a safe operator on there `return unless input_file_path&.end_with?(".xslx")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @razvans points out, the error message here is great.

##### The Error

You're initializing your object with `input_file_path: nil`, and then inside of `call` you're checking if `@input_file_path` (set to `input_file_path` in the initializer, AKA `nil`) *ends with* a string.

There is no `.end_with?` method on `nil`. That's causing the `NoMethodError` error.

##### The Solution

You could guard against `nil` in your `end_with?` call, or give it a default value in the initializer.

Comment: `@input_file_path = input_file_path.to_s` seems like a fairly simple solution to this problem

Comment: @engineersmnky agreed. Although the `nil.to_s == ''`  behavior of Ruby sometimes surprises me! If that reads well, go for it.

Comment: `return unless input_file_path.end_with?(".xslx")` would result in `nil` the same way "/path/to/file.txt" would so it seems like a logical solution to me.